# Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_DeleteObject

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am getting the following error while building a dll with MFC statically linked. There is no much information about this function available. Can anyone please tell me know what library i have to include to get rid of this error?

> Error LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __imp_DeleteObject

I am using Visual Studio 2019

Comment: `__imp_DeleteObject` is the symbol used by the import library. The function that's being imported is [`DeleteObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-deleteobject), so you'll want to link against *Gdi32.lib*.

Comment: That said, you probably **don't** want to statically link against MFC. That's entirely challenging to get right.